# How to paste text in google colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using jupyter notebook on google colaboratory, but when I try to paste text content copied from docx or ppt, it is pasted as an image (it starts as ![image.pdata:image/png;base64,...])

There is no "paste as text" option... For now, I need to type directly on google colaboratory. As I need a complementary ppt file, I copy the text content from the google colaboratory's jupyter notebook to the ppt file... But the problem is there are some contents I have already typed on ppt and Docx...

There is a way to paste text as text in the text cell in jupyter notebook from the google colaboratory?

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an elegant answer, but in my case performing the following sequence worked.

- Copy from ppt or docx, paste into notepad
- Copy from notepad, paste into text cell of google colab
- Copy from text cell, paste into code cell of google colab

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl + V after locating the cell you want to paste the information in.

Answer (score 0):

Google Collab only allows pasting of plain text.

1. Paste it into your browser url box to convert to plain text.
2. Copy from the url box.
3. Paste into Google collab.